# How can I compile files separately with gcj?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, gcj

I use gcj (Cygwin version) to compile 2 java files

$ gcj --version
gcj (GCC) 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Here's my 2 java files:

$ cat MyClass.java

```
public class MyClass {  
   public MyClass() {  
      System.out.println("Hello, MyClass");  
   }  
}
```

$ cat HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {  
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      MyClass myclass = new MyClass();  
      System.out.println("Hello, World");  
   }   
}
```

I'm able to execute the code in HelloWorld with

```
$ gcj.exe -o hello --main=HelloWorld --classpath=. HelloWorld.java MyClass.java
```

I would like to compile them separatly like

```
gcj.exe -C MyClass.java
```

then

```
gcj.exe  --main=HelloWorld --classpath=. HelloWorld.java
```

The problem is that I get

```
/tmp/ccKwa7F4.o: In function '_ZN10HelloWorld4mainEP6JArrayIPN4java4lang6StringEE':  
/home/lucm/HelloWorld.java:3: undefined reference to `MyClass::class$'  
/home/lucm/HelloWorld.java:3: undefined reference to `MyClass::MyClass()'  
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I strongly recommend that you stop using this obsolete toy and start using a real version of Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When compiling to .o, the linkage model is basically C-like.  You have to compile all the files.  So what you would do is compile each to a .o and link the results:

```
gcj -c MyClass.java
gcj -c HelloWorld.java
gcj --main=HelloWorld MyClass.o HelloWorld.o
```

There are some exceptions to this rule with later versions of gcj, when the binary compatibility ABI was introduced.  The above is the most basic way to make it work.